# Custom (or native Android 5) Notification Center on Android 5 device with ZenUI

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, launcher, notification-bar

My ZenPad S 8.0 comes with Android 5.0 and ZenUI launcher on top of it. I can replace the launcher and desktop environment with something like Nova Launcher that feels more native, but when it comes to notification center (the dropdown thing with notification descriptions), I could not find any reasonable alternative that could replace the (imho, ugly) ZenUI notification panel with something custom or just revert back the default\native Android 5 one. The only thing I found is the [Material Status Bar Lollipop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.treydev.msb) app for Android 4.* that does the job (replace the dropdown notification area with custom - more native looking one), but does not work very smoothly on Android 5.

So I'd love to replace this:

[image]

with this:

[image]

Thank you.

**udp** I have found the [slowball](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snowball.app) app that somewhat does what I want (not very smoothly, but still), but I'm still wondering if there're any other custom notification center apps for Android 5 or any way to use the stock one instead of ZenUI?

[image]

Comment: It won't come as an app. You'll have to decompile SystemUI.apk, change the xml files (for icon sizes, colors, etc.), or if you just want to change the graphics, no need to decompile, just replace the .png files after renaming .apk to .zip.

Comment: @AaronGillion , thank you! I don't actually know how does it work, but it seems to me that snowball somehow manages that by "hooking" a slide-down gesture and running itself as a custom notification center; I suspect ZenUI notification thing works similarly - that is not the "skin" over stock notification center (with icons or fonts replace by custom ones), but must be a standalone app, I guess?